# Connection pooling issue using pyodbc on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, odbc, connection-pooling, pyodbc

I am refactoring some old code to handle SQL connection in a more consistent manner. Now, I have read about connection pooling and I wanted to check whether this was supported. In order to check this, I have run the following code:

```
import pyodbc

def runQuery(con, query, parameters=None):
    result = list()

    if parameters is None:
        parameters = ()

    with con.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(query, parameters)

        column_names = [col[0] for col in cur.description]
        result = [
            dict(zip(column_names, row))
            for row in cur.fetchall()
        ]

    return result

conn1 = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                            f'SERVER={server};'
                            f'DATABASE={database};'
                            f'UID={username};'
                            f'PWD={password}')

with conn1:
    result1 = runQuery(conn1, 'SELECT @@SPID')
    print(result1)


conn2 = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                            f'SERVER={server};'
                            f'DATABASE={database};'
                            f'UID={username};'
                            f'PWD={password}')

with conn2:
    result2 = runQuery(conn2, 'SELECT @@SPID')
    print(result2)
```

which results in

```
[{'': 76}]
[{'': 79}]
```

Is this the correct way of testing whether connection pooling is being used? If so, does this in fact indicate that this is not the case here?

My `odbcinst.ini` file contains the following:

```
[ODBC]
Pooling=Yes

[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.4.so.1.1
UsageCount=1
```

Environment:

- Python: 3.6.8
- pyodbc: 4.0.30
- unixodbc: 2.3.7
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- DB: SQL Server Azure
- driver: ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Answered on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/774).